# Simple Numeric Regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to strip a `string` to have only numeric values and one decimal point....
What is wrong with my Regex?

```
string test = "1e2e3.e4";
var s = Regex.Replace(test, "^\\d*\\.\\d*$", "");
```

Comment: You're using a regex for matching, but them replacing?  The regex is fine to match what you're looking for.  But if you want to replace away invalid characters, you'll need to define what you want out.  Given `1.2.3.4`, what should be the result? `123.4`?  `1.234`? `12.34`? etc...

Comment: I just want to allow only numbers and decimals points. I will handle a multiple decimal point in a different way depending on some properties of my control... Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is striping away a decimal number, try this instead:

```
Regex.Replace(test, "[^\\d.]", "");
```

If you want to keep just one dot, you first need to determine which dot you want to keep if there's many of them.

**Update**: Assuming you'd want to keep the first or last dot, use `String.IndexOf` or `String.LastIndexOf` to split the string and use:

```
Regex.Replace(test, "\\D", "");
```

on each of the resulting strings. That would be potentially slower than not using regex as in Matt Hamilton answer tough.

Answer (score 1):

Regex might be overkill for your needs.

```
string test = "1e2e3.e4.56543fds.4";

var foundPeriod = false;

var chars = test.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c) 
    || (c == '.' && !foundPeriod && (foundPeriod = true))).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(new String(chars));
```

Comment: wow, very clever. didn't know that assignment returned a value ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "1e2e3.e4";
var s = Regex.Replace(test, @"[^\d\.]", "");
```

Comment: That would leave the '^' characters if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes, you are right, i guess what i was trying to say was, not \d and not \\. don't need the second not

Comment: thanks MARKKAM :) hope this is right this time, i've tested it with some strings, seems to be right now