# Assign and check for a null value at the same time?

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario:

```
if(xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault() != null)
{
    XElement children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is there a way I can check for null and assign the value at the same time instead of having to search for the value twice, something similar to:

```
//Not sure if this is correct.
if (XElement children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault() != null)
{

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[A variable assignment also returns the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value). So the syntax in the form of the following will do:

```
SomeType someVariable;
if ((someVariable = valueToAssign) != null)
{
    // valueToAssign was not null
}
```

In your case:

```
XElement children;

if ((children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault()) != null)
{

}
```

Comment: Ah i had no idea, so my syntax was correct, I just guessed lol

Comment: @Xaisoft Your syntax wasn't correct, you were also declaring it in-line, which isn't valid.

Comment: I like this approach, I didn't notice the double brace at first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it this way:

```
XElement children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault();
if(children != null)
{
    //use children
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing, but if no Children were found, I would get an error.

Comment: @Xaisoft makes no sense, because if that is the case, your code would also throw an error

Comment: No worries! You might also want to check out the  null-coalescing operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Pattern Matching in C# 7

```cs
if(xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault() is XElement children)
{
    xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

*It's a late response, but this question is showing up on top in google, and it's missing a C# 7 answer*

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
XElement children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault();
```

and then check for null

```
if (children != null) {...}
```

Comment: If no Children elements are found, this throws a null exception.

Comment: @Xaisoft: mhh, that should not be the case. It would be the case if you use `First` but `FirstOrDefault` should return null

Comment: When FirstOrDefault says it returns a default value, is that a default value you specify or is it the default value for the specified type, for example, reference variables would get null?

Comment: @Xaisoft: default value for the specified type, null in this case.

Comment: @Xaisoft Likely `default(T)`, which for all reference types is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign and then test the assigned value in a single statement (but not declare it):

```
XElement children = null;

if ((children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault()) != null)
{    
}
```

But this is functionally the same as assigning and testing afterwards:

```
var children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault();

if (children != null)
{      
}
```

I would favour the latter because I think it is more readable (also lets you use `var`).

Assignment of a null value to a variable will never itself generate an error (assuming this is just a standard local variable), subsequent use of that variable might do. So either solution above will be safe assuming `xml` itself isn't null.

Comment: Yes it returns null if no children are found, but that is what I want to avoid having to check for null and then assign the value.

Comment: @Xaisoft It is functionally the same as assigning it and then checking the variable afterwards - just it does it in one line. It isn't doing any less work.

Comment: Nice. I'm going blind, I din't notice the double brace at first, but this works great.

Comment: @Xaisoft Yeah the braces define the precedence, the "result" of the braced code is an `XElement` that can be tested for null.

Comment: Functionally, it's mostly the same, but you can get slightly nicer behaviour if you need to pull different content in multiple if statements: `if ((children = GetChildren1()) != null) {} elseif ((children = GetChildren2()) != null) {} elseif ((children = GetChildren3()) != null){}` though depending on what you're doing there may be a better design than that.  But that's just way only calling GetChildren1/2/3 as needed rather than pre-calling all 3 then doing checks.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'd say functionally the same based on "assignment before condition", but your flow is a nice take on it, and perhaps the only real reason why you might do this. I also do it in while loops: `while ((line = Console.ReadLine()).Length != 0)`, because you get a "free" assignment before the check expressed in the while condition itself, as is the end result in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this though:

```
null != children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Just curious, why the null != first?

Comment: @Xaisoft well no huge reasons -- just my taste --but if you do it the other way around you have to wrap `children = xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault()` in an extra set of parenthesis. Otherwise, the compiler will think you're trying to assign a boolean to `children` (`xml.Descendants(ns + "Children").FirstOrDefault() != null`). If you put `null != ` at the beginning you get to avoid that extra set of paranthesis -- just looks cleaner to my eyes anyway :)