# Enabling a fluent design in c# objects

Tags: c#, fluent

I have a line of C#:

```
cats.Add(new Cat("happy") { Mean=false})
```

I with to modify the Cat and then apply the mean like this:

```
cats.Add(Fix(new Cat("happy")) { Mean=false})
```

but I can't. How what should the Fix() method do in order for the above to work?

Comment: You can't use an initializer with an extension method or any other method wrapping the `new Cat()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work like that. The `new X() { }` is an initializer, and you can't split it up by calling a `Fix` around the constructor then the property / field bindings on the result. Property / field bindings *must* be evaluated before calling the `Fix` function.

You'd have to do this:

```
public Cat Fix(Cat cat) { ... }

cats.Add(Fix(new Cat("happy") { Mean=false }));
```

Or an extension method like this:

```
public static class CatExtensions {
     public static Cat Fix(this Cat cat) { ... }
}

cats.Add(new Cat("happy") { Mean=false }.Fix());
```

Or if you are a little more adventurous, you can accept an dynamic type:

```
public Cat Fix(Cat cat, dynamic properties) { ... }

cats.Add(Fix(new Cat("happy"), new { Mean=false }));

// extension method:
public static class CatExtensions {
     public static Cat Fix(this Cat cat, dynamic properties) { ... }
}

cats.Add(new Cat("happy").Fix(new { Mean=false }));
```

Or a generic method:

```
public Cat Fix<T>(Cat cat, T properties) { ... }

cats.Add(Fix(new Cat("happy"), new { Mean=false }));

// extension method:
public static class CatExtensions {
     public static Cat Fix<T>(this Cat cat, T properties) { ... }
}

cats.Add(new Cat("happy").Fix(new { Mean=false }));
```

Comment: But if Fix modifies the `Mean` property, this won't necessarily have the desired effect.  He'd like to ensure `Mean` is set to false after the object has been created and 'fixed'.

Answer (score 1):

The above is not possible.  An object initializer can only be used alongside a constructor, not on an arbitrary instance.  You'll need to create a temporary variable:

```
var nonMeanCat = Fix(new Cat("happy"));
nonMeanCat.Mean = false;
cats.Add(nonMeanCat);
```

Alternatively, to support a fluent design, add explicit accessor methods for the properties, e.g. `IsMean()` and `Mean(bool)`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you can't do that because the syntax used in the first statement is called Object Initializer Syntax which is supported directly by the C# and can't extended.
A solution is to have the `Fix` method return the `Cat` instance on which it was called, something like this:

```
public class Cat {
    public Cat Fix() {
        // DO YOUR WORK HERE
        return this;
    }

    public Cat Mean(bool meanValue) {
        Mean = meanValue;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
cats.Add(new Cat("Happy").Fix().Mean(meanValue));
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's valid; the assignment of the `Mean` property to `false` would cause the `cats.Add` method to receive an argument of type boolean, as opposed to the expected value of type Cat.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value

Comment: @KenoguLabz, thank you for pointing that out, i wanted to show how could the fluent interface idea be implemented and in the mix i used it the wrong way. any way mistake corrected.