# Variable assignment within method parameter

Tags: c#

I've just found out (by discovering a bug) that you can do this:

```
string s = "3";
int i;
int.TryParse(s = "hello", out i); //returns false
```

Is there a legitimate use of using the returned value of an assignment?

<sub>(Obviously `i++` is, but is this the same?)</sub>

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is a bug.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3807583/187697

Comment: @Arran The bug was that somebody had copied and pasted the signature of a method with an optional parameter and forgot to get rid of the default, causing undesired behaviour. No bugs in the code quoted here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An assignment is an expression just like any other. This is valid syntax.

For the same reason this is valid:

```
int i;
int j;
int k;

i = j = k = 42;
```

Answer (score 7):

Generally I'd avoid using the return value of an assignment as it can all too easily lead to had to spot bugs. However, there is one excellent use for the feature as hopefully illustrated below, lazy initialization:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value { get { return _value ?? (_value = "hello"); } }
}
```

As of C# 6, this can be expressed using the `=>` notation:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value => _value ?? (_value = "hello");
}
```

By using the ?? notation and the return value from the assignment, terse, yet readable, syntax can be used to only initialize the field and return it via a property when that property is called. In the above example, this isn't so useful, but within eg facades that need to be unit tested, only initializing those parts under test can greatly simplify the code.

Comment: Interesting example. Are you missing `return` though?

Comment: +1 for the great idea. need a pair of parenthesis to compile. 
public string Value { get { return _value ?? (_value = "hello"); } }

Comment: @Menol, thanks for spotting that.I've also updated it to mention the optional syntax that can be used with C# 6.

Answer (score 5):

This is legitimate.

`s = "hello"`, is an expression which is evaluated / executed first, and the `int.TryParse` expression is executed after that.

Therefore, `int.TryParse` will use the content of 's' which is at that time "hello" and it's returning false.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a legitimate use of using the returned value of an
>   assignment?

Yes.

From [`= Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand and **returns the value as its result.**

That means `=` doesn't do assignment only, *also it returns the value as an expression*. Inside a method, your `s` reference now points to `"hello"` string not `"3"` anymore..

So,

```
int.TryParse(s = "hello", out i);
```

is evaluated like;

```
int.TryParse("hello", out i);
```

which since `"hello"` is not a valid integer, it returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking:

> Is it useful that assignment to a variable can be used as a value?

One place where it is useful is for daisy-chaining variable assignments:

```
string a, b, c;
a = b = c = "hello";
```

Which is clearer when parenthesized:

```
string a, b, c;
a = (b = (c = "hello"));
```

If `c = "hello"` did not have the value `hello`, then the above would not be possible. It has limited use elsewhere but has no real downside.