# Assigning references values within string.Format()

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have a method which takes in a reference double and returns a string, while also modifying the value of the reference:

```
const long OneKb = 1024;
const long OneMb = OneKb * 1024;
const long OneGb = OneMb * 1024;
const long OneTb = OneGb * 1024;

public string GetLargestDataSizeAndUnitOfMeasurement(ref double value, int decimalPlaces = 0)
{
    var asTb = Math.Round(value / OneTb, decimalPlaces);
    var asGb = Math.Round(value / OneGb, decimalPlaces);
    var asMb = Math.Round(value / OneMb, decimalPlaces);
    var asKb = Math.Round(value / OneKb, decimalPlaces);
    string unit = asTb > 1 ? string.Format("Tb", value = asTb)
    : asGb > 1 ? string.Format("Gb", value = asGb)
    : asMb > 1 ? string.Format("Mb", value = asMb)
    : asKb > 1 ? string.Format("Kb", value = asKb)
    : string.Format("B", value = Math.Round(value, decimalPlaces));
    return unit;
}
```

My question is whether it's acceptable to assign the reference a new value **within** the `string.Format()`, despite the value not being pertinent to that method itself. I could execute the `if` separately to modify `value` if I wanted to avoid this, but this seems cleaner and potentially more efficient at scale.

Comment: `string.Format("Tb", value = asTb)` this will return "Tb". Why are you using format at all? And that does not look cleaner. It is ugly and confusing.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri that's kind of my question, the `string.Format()` allows me to update the reference inline while also returning the string I need. I just want to know if that's frowned upon or not, and why.

Comment: Assignment is a **valid** C# expression, and since you are using a **valid** C# construct, why shouldn't it be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I really **don't see anything wrong** with doing assignment calls within a `string.format` method. But by looking at the given code, it could be avoided.

If you looking for cleaner code you could use an **enum** to store your data unit names and you could **reduce the amount of variables** you declaring. This way your code is **more maintainable** and if ever you want to use a higher data size unit you could just **add it to enum list**.

```
    public class DataSizeFormatter
    {
        const int OneKB = 1024;

        private enum DataSizes
        {
            B,
            KB,
            MB,
            GB,
            TB
        }

        public string GetLargestDataSizeAndUnitOfMeasurement(ref double value, int decimalPlaces = 0)
        {
            var highestExponent = (int)(Math.Log(value, OneKB));        // Get the highest power which you could assign to 1024 that would not be greater than the given value.
            var lengthOfDataSizeEnum = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DataSizes)).Length;     //Get the length of the enum list

            int highestExponentWithLimit = highestExponent < lengthOfDataSizeEnum ? highestExponent : lengthOfDataSizeEnum - 1;   //If the given value could be divided by a higher data unit than in your enum list then only use your highest data size unit.

            value = Math.Round(value / Math.Pow(OneKB, highestExponentWithLimit), decimalPlaces);   //round of your given value to the approriate data size.

            return ((DataSizes)highestExponentWithLimit).ToString();    //return the data size that was used to round of your given value.

        }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Have a look at these similar questions which explains why it's fine to do assignments within parameters:
[Variable assignment within method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978689/variable-assignment-within-method-parameter)
and
[Why do assignment statements return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value/3807583#3807583).

**UPDATE 2:**

The question around a best approach to converting bytes to higher data storage units has been answered here:
[Does .NET provide an easy way convert bytes to KB, MB, GB, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488796/does-net-provide-an-easy-way-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc).

Answer (score 0):

While having an assignment, `value = asTb`, inside of a String.Format() is valid. In terms of readability and way in which String.Format() is being used is unexpected behaviour.

[MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) states the reason for using String.Format() as:

> Use String.Format if you need to insert the value of an object,
>   variable, or expression into another string

Base on your code snippet this is not your intention. You simply want to return a formatted file size and its corresponding symbol.

```
public class FileSizeConverter
{
    public enum FileSizeSymbol
    {
        B,
        KB,
        MB,
        GB,
        TB
    }

    public string FormatByteSize(ref double fileSize, int decimalPlaces = 0)
    {
        var unit = FileSizeSymbol.B;
        while (fileSize >= 1024 && unit < FileSizeSymbol.TB)
        {
            fileSize = fileSize / 1024;
            unit++;
        }

        fileSize = Math.Round(fileSize, decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        return unit.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a small class which has Value and Unit properties, a ToString method and a constructor which takes a double as a parameter.  Maybe call it DimensionedNumber.

Now you just create a DimensionedNumber by passing value to the constructor.  If you want to display the DimensionedNumber you can just use the ToString() method.

Something like

```
public class DimensionedNumber
{
    public double Value{get; private set;}
    public string Dimension {get; private set;}

    const double OneKb = 1024.0;
    const double OneMb = OneKb * OneKb;
    const double OneGb = OneMb * OneKb;
    const double OneTb = OneGb * OneKb;

    public DimensionedNumber(double value)
    {
        if (value > OneTb) {
            Value = value / OneTb;
            Dimension = "Tb";
        } else if (value > OneGb) {
            Value = value / OneGb;
            Dimension = "Gb";
        } else if (value > OneMb) {
            Value = value / OneMb;
            Dimension = "Mb";
        } else if (value > OneKb) {
            Value = value / OneKb;
            Dimension = "Kb";
        } else {
            Value = value;
            Dimension = "";
        }
    }

    public string ToString(int decimalPlaces)
    {
        return Value.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces.ToString()) + Dimension;
    }
}
```

You would use it with

```
var displayValue = new DimenesionedNumber(12345678.9);
Console.WriteLine(displayValue.ToString(3));  // Three decimal places
```