# Ternary Statement Inline If Not Compiling

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I am trying to run this inline if statement

```
pRun.StartInfo.FileName = File.Exists("C:\\Test\\Data\\TestingPurposes\\" + UserName 
+ "DailyInfo") ? pRun.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true : MessageBox.Show("Please 
verify that this file exists");
```

But I am getting a compile error of:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'bool' and 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult'

How can I remove this error and run the below statement?  What I want to do is check if the file exists, if it does, open it.  If it does not then produce the `messagebox` with said message.

Comment: You have some syntactical errors, but what you want to achieve by this code?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I want to check if the file exists.  If the file does exist open the file, if it does not produce said MessageBox.

Comment: Why on earth would you not want to use an ordinary `if` statement here?

Comment: If the file exists, you are trying to assign `pRun.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` to `pRun.StartInfo.FileName`.

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense... you're trying to set the filename to the result of this ternary operation... but the result is either a statement (...UseShellExecute = true) or a MessageBox. That's just... odd...

Comment: [`MessageBox.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't return a bool; it returns a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx). So, you need to make it a boolean expression by comparing its value `MessageBox.Show(...) == DialogResult.OK`. That said, I wouldn't do that with a ternary operator. It's just a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use ternary operator, both statement should return the same type or one type should be convertible to other.See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

You need to use simple `if` statements intead, it is also more *readable*:

```
if(File.Exists("C:\\Test\\Data\\TestingPurposes\\" + UserName + "DailyInfo"))
{ 
   pRun.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true   
}
else MessageBox.Show("Please verify that this file exists");
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'll just use a simple if statement.

Comment: _"Your first expression [...] doesn't return anything, it's just an assignment."_ I'm afraid that's not right, i.e.: `bool x; Console.Write(x = true); // true`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3807583/621962).

Comment: @canon you are right, I didn't think that carefully.that is completely valid,thanks for pointing it out, the only problem is expressions returns different values and both are not assignable or convertible to `FileName` which is probably  a string.