# How to select existing objects in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table Companies

```
CompanyId
CountryId
and so on...
```

And then have a list of objects with following structure (let's name this list dataset)

```
Id
CountryId
CurrencyId
TotalCost
and so on...
```

and what I'm trying to do is to get all companies which exists in above dataset,
so I'm trying to write query like:

```
IEnumerable<Company> companies = db.Companies.Where(a=a.CompanyId == dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).ToList()
```

but it gives me an error,

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of typ int and List

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: You can't use this: `Where(a=a.CompanyId == dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId)`. But you can use `Where(a => a.CompanyId == companyId` where `companyId = dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: You need to convert dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).ToList()  to int and then compare

Comment: db.Companies.Where(a=>dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).Contains(a.CompanyId)).ToList(); //Assuming dataset companyid is an int

Comment: As a complement, note that `myVar = someInt` returns an int, this is why you get this exception: it tries to compare `int` and `List`. Find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3807583/9757968

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Company> companies = db.Companies.Where(a=> dataset.Select(b=>b.CompanyId).Contains(a.CompanyId)).ToList()
```

Try this , you are trying to use list of int == on single int variable .. use contains to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> companyIds = dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).ToList();
IEnumerable<Company> companies = db.Companies.Where(a=> companyIds.Contains(a.CompanyId));
```

You can pre-calculate the company ids to be searched and then use `Contains` method of `List<T>` to match the company ids.

Answer (score 0):

`dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId)` return a `List`, so you can't compare your simple `CompanyId` type `int` with this `List`

You must check if an object with his `CompanyId` being in this list allowed or not by the method `Contains`

```
var companies = db.Companies.Where(a=> dataset.Select(a=>a.CompanyId).Contains(a.CompanyId))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Contains()` like this:

```
var companies = new List<(int companyid, int countryid, string companyName)>()
{
    (1, 2, "One Incorporated"),
    (2, 5, "Two-two Ltd"),
    (3, 24, "Mr-Three Ltd")
};

var other = new List<(int companyid, string stuff)>()
{
    (1, "asdad"),
    (2, "asdadv")
};

var inOther = companies.Where(x => other.Select(y => y.companyid).Contains(x.companyid));
```

This would output "One Incorporated" and "Two-two Ltd".

other.Select(y => y.companyid) gets your list of ID's then Contains() checks to see if x's (x being the company in the where statement) ID exists.