# null coalescing operator in return statements- c#

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have used [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) in return statements like below

```
return Variable??"undefined";
```

But the below code,

```
return Variable??Variable="undefined";
```

I could not understand how it works, since the second parameter to the operator is a assignment statement and i wonder how the return works.

could some one help me understand

Comment: The return-value of an assignement is the value being assigned, so `Variable = "undefined"` returnes `"undefined"`. This can then be returned by your method.

Comment: The second line of code is both assigning a value to `Variable` if it's null, and returning the value of `Variable`. It's the same as: `if (Variable == null) Variable = "undefined"; return Variable;` This is different than the first line, which will return "undefined" if `Variable` is `null`, but will not assign that value to `Variable` (it will remain `null` after the return).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do assignment statements return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value)

Comment: While I do not recommend it, something like `A = B = 2;` is valid code, and is the same reason why this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator):

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand and **returns the value as its result**

So the return-value of an assignement is the value being assigned. `Variable = "undefined"` therefor returns `"undefined"`. This can then be returned by your method. The `??` on the other hand is just a shorthand for a simple if-statement.

So the following is fairly similar to your code:

```
if(Variable != null)
    return Variable
Variable = "undefined";
return Variable;
```

Comment: Does that mean i can do assignment to a variable not the same as the variable mentioned in the left hand side of the operator?

Comment: @SamuelAC Sure, try it out. As assignement is just a statement as any other.

Comment: I get it, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In C# the assign operation also returns the value that was assigned.
For example

```
Value=Value=Value=Value="Hello World"
```

Is valid code. The Assignment get's evaluated first from right to left. In your case assignment>null coalescing operator.
You coudl rewrite your code to

```
string returnValue="";
if(Variable==null)
    returnValue=Variable="undefined";
else
    returnValue=Variable;
return returnValue;
```