# Getting assignment expressions value before assignment in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

Right now I can do this:

```
public static void Swapper (ref int a, ref int b) {
       b = (a = a + b) - b;
       a = a - b;
}
```

But I want to be able to do this:

```
public static void Swapper (ref int a, ref int b) {
      a = (b = a);
}
```

So, I want the assignment expression to return the original value of the left operand before it gets changed. This is a syntax-related question, and I'm looking for a general solution that works for all cases, not just the specific example provided. Is this possible?

**Edit**

I'm aware of:

```
(a, b) = (b, a);
```

This specific case is just an example used to illustrate what I want syntax-wise. Is just a dummy method. I don't have a need to swap two variables.

Basically I have `++i` and I want `i++`.

**Edit 2**

In Python the functionality for returning the value  in an assignment expression is achieved by the walrus operator `:=`. Let's assume this new operator that returns the left-hand side first is expressed like `=:`, a reverse walrus operator.

Then when traversing some kind of linked list, for example, we could do (in C#):

```
while (x != null && y != null) {
    node = (node.next = (x.value > y.value) ? new Node(x =: x.next) : new Node(y =: y.next));
}
```

vs

```
while (x != null && y != null) {
    if (x.value > y.value) {
        node = (node.next = new Node(x));
        x = x.next;
    } else {
        node = (node.next = new Node(y));
        y = y.next;
    }
}
```

Anyway, this is probably convoluted and rarely useful, but seems a bit more elegant to me.

Comment: Why not `(a, b) = (b, a);` to swap values?

Comment: The basic idea of line-of-business languages such as C# is to *clearly communicate the algorithm to the reader of the code*, not to make tiny puzzle boxes that the reader has to figure out. Can you say a little more about what problem you're actually trying to solve here? If you want the value of a variable before the variable is modified, *store it in a local*. Naming storage of temporary values is the whole *purpose* of having locals in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tuple` to swap values:  [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0180)

```
public static void Swapper(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    (a, b) = (b, a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't possible.

From the C# spec: *"The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value."*

This is paraphrased in Microsoft's C# documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator).

So the result of `(b = a)` will be the value assigned to `b`. It isn't possible for this assignment expression somehow to return the original of value of `b`.

I would strongly recommend reading Eric Lippert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807192/why-do-assignment-statements-return-a-value). (And anything else you can find by Eric Lippert on this or any other topic.)

Comment: LOL. You're very kind.